# I use random() in a code to calcuate the times to win, but the result is as expected

Tags: python, random

```
def simNGame(probA, probB, n):
# simulate n games 
# prob is the chance to win of person A or person B, n is the times of games
# return the number of wins of A and B
winsA = 0
winsB = 0
for i in range(n):
    scoreA, scoreB = simOneGame(probA, probB)
    if scoreA > scoreB:
        winsA += 1
    else:
        winsB += 1
return winsA, winsB

def simOneGame(probA, probB):
    # simulate 1 game
    # return the score of A and B
    scoreA = 0
    scoreB = 0
    serving = 'A'
    while not gameOver(scoreA, scoreB):
        if serving == 'A':
            if probA > random():
                scoreA += 1
            else:
                serving = 'B'
        else:
            if probB > random():
                scoreB += 1
            else:
                serving = 'A'
    return scoreA, scoreB

def gameOver(scoreA, scoreB):
    # check the game is over or not
    return scoreA == 15 or scoreB == 15
```

This code is used to simulated the racquetaball.
when I ran it with two people with same changce to win, I noticed that winsB was always 4700+ and winsA was always 5200+, so I try this:

```
while True:
    a, b = simNGame(0.5, 0.5, 10000)
    print a > b
```

All of the results is True, but I cannot check any errors in my code.why,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial serving is always 'A', which is not fair.
You just need to apply this modification

```
# not fair
serving = 'A'

# note: we assume probA + probe == 1.0

# initial serving is decided by players' skill
serving = 'A' if probA > random() else 'B'

# or, initial serving is decided by a coin
serving = 'A' if 0.5 > random() else 'B'
```

Comment: I don't know the game, but is it accurate that a player's skill impacts their probability of serving? I would have expected this one to be an unweighted random selection.

Comment: I guest most game in real world would not go in this way, a flip of coin would be enough. Maybe I should modify the answer to fix at 50/50 for playerA and plyerB, and ignore their skill.